# AltBeacon Android - How I can force update the UUID and Name of a beacon?

Tags: android, altbeacon, beacon

I am making a application that recognize beacons in a region. The beacon's UUID is constantly changing, but the AltBeacon Library returns just the first finded UUID info.

My code:

```
@Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            // Here, i get the UUID String... but is the same I already finded in the last call of this method 
        }
```

Is this method correct to get the UUID that is constantly updating?

Comment: Welcome to SO, you would be pleased to provide the faulty source code in order to have some help.

Comment: Showing your code would be helpful, yes.  The Android Beacon Library is designed to return whatever beacon identifiers it detects, updating every second using ranging APIs.    So if the identifier changes you should see a new value in the next ranging update.

Comment: I edited my post, can you review it? Thanks for the comment, and sorry for my english :)